# I want to extract shortest length matching string in a file in TCL?

Tags: arrays, regex, pattern-matching, tcl

I have a file that contain the following line in any order:

```
1. A/B/C/D/E
2. A/B/C/D
3. X/Y/Z
4. X/Y
5. R/S/T/Q
6. L/M/N/O/P
7. L/M
```

With this I want an output as:

```
1. A/B/C/D
2. X/Y
3. R/S/T/Q
4. L/M
```

Basically, among the matHcing string I want to take the shortest one.

Comment: I don't understand the format you are using to specify the lines. Can you please add another example? Are each of the numbered items possible lines?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Your question is not clear, yet.  Suppose the input list also contained four extra lines, containing just `A`, `X`, `R`, and `L`.  Would it then be correct that the output should be those four letters?  So, for each distinct starting letter, you want the shortest common prefix for all the lines with that starting letter?  Suppose there was also a line `A/C/E/G` in the input; would the output include just `A`, or `A/B/C/D` and also `A/C/E/G`?  Suppose the line `A` was not in the input, but `A/C/E/G` was: what is the expected output?

Comment: yes if input constains just A,X,R,L. output should be these four letters.  if A/C/E/G is also present i want output to be A.   if A  is not in the input and A/C/E/G then output should be A/C/E/G

Answer (score 1):

**Input.txt**

```
A/B/C/D/E 
A/B/C/D  
X/Y/Z 
X/Y 
R/S/T/Q 
L/M/N/O/P  
L/M
```

**extractShortString.tcl**

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set fp [open input.txt r]
set data [read $fp]
close $fp
# Put the data in an array
foreach line $data {
    set config($line) 1
}
set t [lsort $data]
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $t]} {incr i} {
    set elem [lindex $t $i]
    # Extracting all the matching string with that element
    # from the array
    set matches [lsort [array names config $elem*]]
    # If it is matching only one, then simply
    # add it to the 'result'
    if {[llength $matches]==0} {
        lappend result $elem
        continue
    }
    # Getting the shortest string from index 0
    set short_str [lindex $matches 0]
    # Adding it to the 'result'
    lappend result $short_str
    # Finally, need to increment the 'i' 
    # to skip the other matching elements
    incr i [expr {[llength $matches]-1}]
}

foreach el $result {
    puts $el
}
```

**Output**

```
A/B/C/D
L/M
R/S/T/Q
X/Y
```

Comment: I dont have input in a txt file, I have it in an array i.e arr($input_lines)

Comment: @MayankGoyal: this code gets the input in an array called `$data` (instead of `$input_lines` — otherwise, it does what you need.  That sort of difference is trivial and you should be able to see past it very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `struct::set` if you have access to the Tcl standard library to intersect the allowed strings and the lines of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

package require Tcl 8.0
package require struct::set

# list of qualifying strings
set legal_strings [lreplace [split [read [open [lindex $argv 0] "r"]]] end end]

proc compare_length {a b} {
    set len_a [string length $a]
    set len_b [string length $b]
    if {$len_a < $len_b} {
        return -1
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

set lines [split [read [open [lindex $argv 1] "r"]]]

puts [lsort -command compare_length [::struct::set intersect $lines $legal_strings]]
```

Comment: I can not make a list of legal strings. These can vary.

Comment: are you storing them in a file?

Comment: I have an array which contains strings line by line  as i have mentioned in input. these will vary. i want to extract the lowest of the matching string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of strings to be processed is in the variable `strings`:

```
set items [lassign [lsort $strings] item0]
lappend items {}

set result {}

foreach item $items {
    if {![string match $item0* $item]} {
        lappend result $item0
        set item0 $item
    }
}
```

Sorting the list means that all result strings come before the strings that match them, i.e. are longer versions of the result string. The loop skips over all strings that match the current result string (`$item0`) and collects the result strings in a list (`result`). A sentinel item (`{}`) is added to the `items` list to ensure that the last result string is collected.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)